# Display japanese characters in java

Tags: java, encoding

I am reading a String from Oracle DB and trying to print it to the Standard Output, however I am printing different string from what I see after I retrieved it

```
 package project1;

public class testJapChar {
    public testJapChar() {
        super();
    }


public static void main(String[] argv){ 
        String str = "新人研修交通費　";
        System.out.println("Original String : " + str);                      
    }
```

}

The result of the Execution is : **Original String : æ–°äººç ”ä¿®äº¤é€šè²»ã€€
**

I am running this script in Jdeveloper and My my environment encoding is set to  UTF-8.

Upd. I compiled this code with -encoding option "UTF-8", however the output was : Original String : 7/31????????

Comment: If you run it on the command line does it work as expected?

Comment: Looks like utf-8 -> iso-latin-1

Comment: This works fine for me in Eclipse as long as I save the Java file as UTF-8.  From your output it looks like you're sending the correct bytes but whatever displays them is not expecting UTF-8.

Comment: I printed it from the command line and got this : Original String : µû░Σ║║τáöΣ┐«Σ║ñΘÇÜΦ▓╗πÇÇ.  I setup an environment Encoding to "UTF-8", default was "Cp1252". I played with the different env encodings and still didn't receive the desired output.

Comment: Try here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html